# How can we prove that we've discovered a strange attractor?

Tags: recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems, intuition, nonlinear-system

So, [this webpage](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html) has a strange attractor of the form:

$$x_{n+1} = a x_n + y_n$$
$$y_{n+1} = b + (x_n)^2$$

...it precedes the graphic of a strange attractor itself  (the initial conditions are also given for the strange attractor).  My question is, how can we prove that this system defines a strange attractor?  Also, is there any way to get more exact values for the system - for example, more accurate numbers?

**EDIT**

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2017231) for a general reference on chaos and strange attractors.  For this question (the current question), I'm wondering what exactly we need to do to prove that we have a strange attractor.  In other words, the last question was a reference request, and this question is the mathematics itself - how do we go about proving that we've found a strange attractor?

Comment: @TheGeekGreek:  I asked that question myself.  That was supposed to be for a general reference on chaos, etc.  I'm trying to learn, for this question, what we need to know to prove that we have a strange attractor.